# Windows Embedded CE 6.0 USB Printer Driver

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

I am going to write USB printer driver for Windows Embedded CE 6.0.
But I dont from where to start.
Now I installed VS2005, patches of WinCE6.0, VS2005 team suite SP1, Platform Builder SP1, R2,R3.

Tell me how to start to write the driver, whether from VS 2005.
In which application I am going to write the driver application. 
How to use platform Builder, how PB is helpful for me to write the USB driver.

I have Win CE 6.0 device is with me.
Plz help me .

When Printer connected to device, device gives error for "give the driver name for printer",
I tried by giving pcl.dll.
tell me how to use pcl.dll also

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the documentation for Windows CE 5.0, I don't imagine WinCE 6 being much different.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa447572.aspx

> **Printer Driver Samples**
>
> ...
>
> Two printer driver samples are available to you: A generic printer driver, called Pcl.dll, **and a USB printer driver**.